# php increment field value in mysql

Tags: php, html

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> 
    <ul> 
        <input type="radio" name="team" id="1" value="Real Madrid" size='5'><font size='5'><u> Real Madrid<br> 
        <input type="radio" name="team" id="2" value="Chelsea"> Chelsea<br> 
        <input type="radio" name="team" id="3" value="Milan"> Milan<br>
        <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="VOTE" >

</form>
```

this is my button in html

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $selected_radio = $_POST['id'];
   $query = "UPDATE favourite_team SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE id = '" .  $selected_radio . "'";
   $q = mysqli_query($conn, $query);}
```

this is my code in php

Comment: Your question is not so clear. What's the error? What you are expecting?

Comment: What is the issue? Please specify your question so one can able to give proper answer.

Comment: what have to be done? specify it!

Comment: I expect when click the button to increase likes with 1. When I click the button nothing happen

Comment: Show your complete form along with your database connection!!

Comment: Is your code contains form? because submit button works within <form> tag only.

Comment: <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <ul>
            <input type="radio" name="team" id="1" value="Real Madrid" size='5'><font size='5'><u> Real Madrid<br>
            <input type="radio" name="team" id="2" value="Chelsea"> Chelsea<br>
            <input type="radio" name="team" id="3" value="Milan"> Milan<br> <input type="radio" name="team" id="25" value="Everton"> Everton<br></font></u>
            <br>
        </ul>
        <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="VOTE" >
    </form>    this at the end is my button

Comment: In PHP, you have `$selected_radio = $_POST['id'];` but on the form, there is no input element with the name `id`. It should be `$selected_radio = $_POST['team'];`

Comment: I fixed $selected_radio = $_POST['id'] to $selected_radio = $_POST['team'] but it doesn't help

Comment: See my answer. you have to change a bit in `<form></form>` too

Answer (score 1):

Name is 'team'. Not, 'id'. Use this code. Give `id` value to `value` attribute

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> 
    <ul> 
        <input type="radio" name="team" value="1" size='5'><font size='5'><u> Real Madrid<br> 
        <input type="radio" name="team" value="2" > Chelsea<br> 
        <input type="radio" name="team" value="3" > Milan<br>
        <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="VOTE" >

</form>

<?
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $selected_radio = $_POST['team'];
   $query = "UPDATE favourite_team SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE id = '" .  $selected_radio . "'";
   $q = mysqli_query($conn, $query);}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the value of the radio to be the id this mean value='1'

and need to change 
$selected_radio = $_POST['id']; **to** 
 $selected_radio = $_POST['team'];

**and change input type to submit type='submit'**

```
<input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit' value='VOTE'>
```

i hope this will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `$_POST['team']`. Try this code:-

```
 $selected_radio = $_POST['team'];
 $query = "UPDATE favourite_team SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE id = '" .  $selected_radio . "'";
 $q = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Check this [link](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php4p10.html) for more detail.